# Updating core to a specific version with Composer

Tags: 8, updating, composer

My site hasn't been updated for two months, a few new updates has been released. 
My site's core version is 8.5.6.
Before running `composer update -with-dependencies` I read the release notes to the latest version of core (8.6.2), they say:

> Sites on 8.5.x should update immediately to Drupal 8.5.8 instead, and
>   plan to update to the latest 8.6.x release before May 2019.

How do I update the old core to Drupal 8.5.8 instead? 
How do I specify that version in CLI, what command?
Eventually I want to update it to the latest version.

Comment: `composer require drupal/core:8.5.8 --update-with-dependencies`, or some slight variation. If you get complaints about conflicting symfony component, add `symfony/config` to your command. If you have `webflo/drupal-core-strict` installed, also add that

Answer (score 2):

I was in the same position. I used :

```
composer require drupal/core:^8.5.10
```

And it worked. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

If [your project uses drupal/core-recommended](https://www.drupal.org/docs/updating-drupal/updating-drupal-core-via-composer#s-verify-if-the-project-uses-drupalcore-recommended-or-drupalcore) you can execute this command to update your site to a specific release :

```
composer require drupal/core-recommended:9.2.16 drupal/core-composer-scaffold:9.2.16 drupal/core-project-message:9.2.16 --update-with-all-dependencies
```